# Simple way to expose a Python app over a public IP on Azure Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, docker-container, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

I have a deployed a K8s cluster on AKS using Terraform. I am unable to expose the Python service I used with a LoadBalancer. Below are my files;

**Cluster information:**

Kubernetes version: 1.19.0

Cloud being used: Azure

Installation method: Terraform

**deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: identity
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: identity-svc
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: identity-svc
    env: dev
    app: identity-svc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: MC_identity-k8s-rg_identity-k8s-aks_westeurope
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: identity-svc
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: 50aXR5MngwIn19fQ...
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: acr-secret
  namespace: default
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: identity-deploy
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: identity-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: identity-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: default
      labels:
        app: identity-svc
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: acr-secret
      containers:
      - name: identityservice
        image: identityservice.azurecr.io/identityservice:${{ github.run_id }}
        env:
          - name: SECRET_KEY
            value: ${secrets.SECRET_KEY}
          - name: ALLOWED_HOSTS
            value: ${secrets.ALLOWED_HOSTS}
          - name: DATABASE_HOST
            value: ${secrets.DATABASE_HOST}
          - name: DEBUG
            value: true
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: "500Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: "1000Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: http
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**service.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: identity-svc
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: identity-svc
    env: dev
    app: identity-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: identity-svc
  type: LoadBalancer 
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000
    name: http
```

When I check kubectl logs I see the pod, service, endpoint are running as supposed to. But external IP as shown below doesn’t load up the Python app.

```
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
identity-svc   LoadBalancer   10.0.145.221   51.105.173.89   80:31723/TCP   95m
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>          443/TCP          134m
```

What am I missing here? The only strange thing I see is the following;

```
admin@Azure:~$ nslookup identity-svc
Server:         168.63.129.16
Address:        168.63.129.16#53
** server can't find identity-svc: NXDOMAIN
```

My ultimate goal is just to expose my app on an external IP to test out.

I also tried implementing nginx ingress you can see the post about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740298/how-to-expose-an-azure-kubernetes-cluster-with-a-public-ip-address-using-terrafo)

I really appreciate your help, and can gladly provide any other information if needed. Thanks

Comment: Show the pods status and test your pod with port-forward.

Comment: Any more updates on the question? Does the port-forward work fine?

Comment: What error do you get? Maybe cloud firewall is blocking the connection.